# Jetpack Compose Testing: Assert specific image is set

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have an `Image` in compose like the following:

```
Image(
    bitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.testimage),
    contentDescription = null, // Only decorative image
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
    modifier = Modifier
        .requiredHeightIn(max = 250.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .semantics { testTag = "MyTestTag" },
)
```

During an Instrumentation test I want to make sure the correct drawable is set. I did not find anything to achieve this in classes like `SemanticsProperties` to write a custom matcher. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 23):

You can add a semantic yourself.

```
val DrawableId = SemanticsPropertyKey<Int>("DrawableResId")
var SemanticsPropertyReceiver.drawableId by DrawableId

val resId = R.drawable.my_drawable
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = resId),
    contentDescription = null,
    Modifier.semantics { drawableId = resId }
)
```

And test it with

```
fun hasDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int): SemanticsMatcher =
    SemanticsMatcher.expectValue(DrawableId, id)

composeRule.onNode(hasDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable))
    .assertIsDisplayed()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to keep things simple and avoid defining your own semantics, use the `testTag`:

```
val resId = R.drawable.some_image
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = resId),
    contentDescription = null,
    Modifier.testTag = resId.toString()
)
```

and in your test:

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(R.drawable.someImage.toString())
    .assertIsDisplayed()
```

Answer (score -7):

You can use espresso for that

```
 Espresso.onView(withId(R.drawable.testimage)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#espresso-interop

The semantics apparently are not aware of what image is displayed.

Comment: you cant use espresso to assert composable views