# How to test Drawable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-jetpack-compose, drawable

I have a Box inside which I am adding image with drawable content.
How can I write UI test for checking drawable is visible or not?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662342/jetpack-compose-testing-assert-specific-image-is-set

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Semantic tree of a compose node, and determine the values of different things.

Check this link for the specifics about how to access and display the Semantic tree in your logcat:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#finders

You will use something like this:

`composeTestRule.onNode(<<SemanticsMatcher>>, useUnmergedTree = false): SemanticsNodeInteraction`

then:

`composeTestRule.onRoot().printToLog("TAG")`

to print the contents to your logcat